# Default parameters with currying

Tags: scala, parameters, currying

I can define a function as:

```
def print(n:Int, s:String = "blah") {}
print: (n: Int,s: String)Unit
```

I can call it with:

```
print(5) 
print(5, "testing")
```

If I curry the above:

```
def print2(n:Int)(s:String = "blah") {} 
print2: (n: Int)(s: String)Unit
```

I can't call it with 1 parameter:

```
print2(5)
<console>:7: error: missing arguments for method print2 in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       print2(5)
```

I have to supply both parameters. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't omit `()` with default arguments:

```
scala> def print2(n:Int)(s:String = "blah") {}
print2: (n: Int)(s: String)Unit

scala> print2(5)()
```

Though it works with implicits:

```
scala> case class SecondParam(s: String)
defined class SecondParam

scala> def print2(n:Int)(implicit s: SecondParam = SecondParam("blah")) {}
print2: (n: Int)(implicit s: SecondParam)Unit

scala> print2(5)
```

Comment: Always remember: an empty argument list is not the same as no argument list.